# problem with very first spring project

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml

I just switched from Striped to Spring but i'm having issues with my very first project,
Basically i get the 404 from the server.
Strange enough, i have followed one by one all the steps in my book.
I use Eclipse, Tomcat 6 and Spring 2.5
The structure of my project is like so:
 src>
  controllers(package)>SpringTestController(implements controller).....then
  ......web content>jsp(folder)>hello.jsp.....then....web-content>web-inf>SpringTest-servlet.xml and web.xml
inside lib i have the 9 necessary jars.

my controller:

```
public class SpringTestController implements Controller{

public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {




    return new ModelAndView("jsp/hello.jsp");
}
```

}

my SpringTest-servet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean name="/hello.htm" class="controllers.SpringTestController"/>

</beans>
```

my web.xml(without header to save space)

```
<servlet>

        <servlet-name>SpringTest</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>

          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>SpringTest</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>
```

Where do you think the problem could be?
I have been trying to look around the files but beside web.xml "where i dont see any abnormality" i'm very new to this flow structure so i really cannot get where the problem is.

Thx for your time

Comment: what about welcome tag in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of the practice of using the *name* attribute of *bean* to specify URL paths - while I'm sure it's probably possible, my answer will tell you how to do it using more traditional means.

First of all, here is the new SpringTest-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="helloController" class="controllers.SpringTestController" />

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/hello.htm">helloController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>   
</bean>
```

You'll probably notice a few things. I'm using the *id* attribute of bean to define your controller so it can be referenced elsewhere (in the *urlMapping* bean as you're about to see).

I define a *urlMapping* bean, which does exactly what you think it does - maps requests (e.g. /hello.htm) to a controller bean.

I've also used viewResolver to map views names to view files, however that is a personal preference thing. Since I'm now using a view resolver, your controller looks like this:

```
public class SpringTestController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("hello");
    }
}
```

I don't need to put the path to the view because the viewResolver prepends it with "/WEB-INF/jsp/" and adds ".jsp" to the end. You can change the *prefix* to wherever you store your view files, or you can not use it at all. It's a personal preference thing, though I like to use it :)

Sorry if this answer didn't conform to your style - I tried to get it working your way and couldn't, so this is how I normally set up a Spring project (if I'm not using annotations).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ben J, thx for the answer, i 've made all the changes you've mentioned but i still get the 404. i have addedd this line in the handleRequest method: System.out.println("handleRequest accessed"); just to see in console if the controller was accessed but nothing, the request does not get that far, i have also added welcome file as hello.jsp but nothing,

Comment: JBoy, I've uploaded my version of your app. Download it here and take a look - perhaps you're missing something small. http://www.prendi.com.au/test.zip

Comment: Hi Ben J, i've imported the project and i still get the 404, i've tested the server (Tomcat 6.0) with other projects (Stripes and simple servlets-mvc) and it works fine, i really dont kno where the problem is

Comment: Hi Ben, i've found a good tutorial on springsource about spring 3, this is working fine, but thank you for your help and your efforts: here's the link http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/?__utma=1.1592083449.1290319199.1290319199.1290319199.1&__utmb=1.3.10.1307860790&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1307861701.1.5.utmcsr=google|utmccn=%28organic%29|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=spring.org&__utmv=-&__utmk=80965783